# create group by button in tree view

Tags: odoo, qweb

In my module, I want to create a button in a tree view that shows the items grouped by month. So to create this button I added this code:

```xml
<t t-extend="ListView">
<t t-jquery=".o_list_view" t-operation="before">   
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oe_my_own_button" accesskey="c">
        <t>Month</t>
    </button>
</t>
</t>
```

And I added this javascript:

```
odoo.define('randa_gamification.filter', function (require) {
"use strict";

var ListView = require('web.ListView');

ListView.include({

render_buttons: function($node) {
    var self = this;
    this._super($node);
    this.$buttons.on('click', '.oe_my_own_button', this.proxy('custom_button_view_action'));
},

custom_button_view_action: function () {

    this.do_action({
        type: "ir.actions.act_window",
        res_model: "gamification.goal",
        view_type : 'tree',
        view_mode : 'form,tree',
        context : '{"search_default_group_by_month": True}',
    });
}

});

});
```

and I implemented this code in assets_backend template. The button is added to my view but it doesn't run the action.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there any error message in your browser console?

Comment: I got this: `unreachable code after return statement`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, take a look at my update

Answer (score 1):

For this you'll need to use a little Javascript:

```
ListView.include({

    render_buttons: function($node) {
        var self = this;
        this._super($node);
        this.$buttons.find('.oe_my_own_button').click(this.proxy('custom_button_view_action'));
    },

    custom_button_view_action: function () {

        this.do_action({
            type: "ir.actions.act_window",
            res_model: "gamification.goal",
            views: [[false,'form']],
            target: 'new',
            view_type : 'form',
            view_mode : 'form',
        });
    }

});
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using a different template, mostly because it makes my Javascript code simpler.

```
  <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
     <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="before">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oe_my_own_button" accesskey="c">
    <t>Month</t>
    </button>
    </t>
  </t>
```

Notice that you'll need to add `oe_my_own_button` class to your button.

Comment: Hey, I tried this code but it didn't work. I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: and where is this button located exactly in this template? I changed the template and the button disappeared.

Comment: You need to change the comment for your button code, see the new update

Comment: I wrote exactly this code I got this error: `QWeb2: Error while extending template 'ListView.buttonsNo expression given`. What I meant by the location is this line: `<t t-jquery=".o_list_view" t-operation="before"> ` this shows that the button is exactly before the list_view. In your code, there's no indication of the position of the button.

Comment: Added the missing `t-jquery` expression. You should also check [this question](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/what-is-t-jquery-in-qweb-72802)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a groupby by defining a searchview in your module like this:

```
<record id="view_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.name</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <search string="">
        <field name="month"/>
        <group expand="0" string="Group By">
            <filter string="Month" icon="terp-go-month" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'month'}"/>
        </group>
    </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a button with javascript that does the groupby.